# How to prove multiplication of natural numbers by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove that there exists a unique function $g : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $x,y ∈ \mathbb{N}$

a) $g(x,1)=x$

b) $g(x,y')=x+g(x,y)$

So my attempt is(rough sketch):

Define $B$ to be the set of all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ so that one can find a set of function values $\{f(x,i):i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ so that for all $y$ both a) and b) holds( for the fixed $x$)

Base step: let $x=1$(keeping $x$ fixed), for every $y \in \mathbb{N}$, define $g(1,y)=y$. So $g(1,1)=1$ and therefore a) holds.
Now, $g(1,y')=1+g(1,y)=y+1$. So b) also holds.
Now let $x \in B$. To show: $x' \in B$. by definition $g(x',1)= x'=(g(x,1))'$
so a) holds.

Here is my problem, how do I show that $g(x',y')=x'+g(x',y)$

hint: Replace the notation $g(x,y)$ by $xy$ (multiplication of $x$ and $y$)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few different ways you can define this type of “multivariate induction”. Since your version of natural numbers does not include $0,$ I will summarize a variation of mathematical induction on two variables accordingly as follows:

> - $P(1,1)$
> - $\forall x\quad P(x,1) \Rightarrow P(x+1,1)$
> - $\forall x,y\quad P(x,y) \Rightarrow P(x,y+1)$
>
> ---
>
> - $\forall x,y\quad P(x,y)$

It is readily verify that first two steps of this algorithm holds for your problem. Now for the last step assume that for some arbitrary $x,$ $g(xy)=xy.$ Then by $b)$ we have $$g(x, y+1)=x+g(xy)=x+xy=x(y+1)$$ as expected, and hence the result followed by mathematical induction.

Comment: Thank you so much Bumblebee! Is there anything wrong in my attempt?

Comment: @NatashaJ: I do not see anything incorrect in your argument. Also I should say that, one can determines $g$ even without induction by applying b) repeatedly (backward) and using a) at the last step as: $$g(x, y)=x+g(x, y-1)=x+x+g(x,y-2)=\underbrace{x+x+\cdots +x}_{y-1\text{ times}}+g(x, 1)=xy.$$

Comment: Thank you for that method! I did not see that.